# CSRF token doesn't work on a live server but works on django's test server

Tags: python, django, nginx, csrf, http-status-code-403

So I have this view:

```
def ocorrenciasRodovia(request,cod=386):
    ctoken = {}
    ctoken.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cod = request.POST.get('idBr')
```

It works on a different way if it comes trough POST method.
The thing is on Django's test server it works just fine BUT when it is live it always give a:
    403 Forbidden
    CSRF Verification failed. Request Aborted.

It says the reason is:
    CSRF token MIssing or incorrect

But I can see it on the code on the live server.
I'm putting it on the template.
Keep in mind it is a very heavy processing view. And it's running on a Nginx Server. And like I said it runs fine locally but on the server it breaks. Is there some kind of configuration necessary on Nginx?

What in hell is happening?

You can see it live here:

http://bit.ly/10DKw9I
if you go to the top right select input, select a number and hit "Buscar" your going to get the error.

Comment: `csrftoken` cookie value differs from the value in `csrfmiddlewaretoken` form field

Comment: Post the complete view method.

Comment: `ctoken.update(csrf(request))` I suspect this line has something do with it